# Managing download of map tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mbtiles, download

I am very new to the world of QGIS and GIS in general.

I have been trying to download very large mbtiles using the Generate XYZ Tiles (MBtiles) option in QGIS 3.18 but my system crashes sometimes and I lose data.

I'm sure I don't fully understand this process but, it seems as though QGIS is downloading a massive amount of tiles from a web-server such as QMS and generating MBtiles from them. My problem is that sometimes this download breaks because of a system crash or otherwise and the process has to be restarted from the beginning.

I have searched for a manager of sorts to pause or resume the download of all this information but to no avail.

Am I doing this wrong or is there a download manager plugin I could install to help me?

Comment: What values (min max zoom) are you using in the processing? it might be too intensive for some setups (hardware/connection/vpn wise).

Comment: thanks for responding. I was attempting levels 0-22 from the ESRI world imagery map

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/zoom-level/ (not sure you will need zooms 19-22) ESRI image resolution is not high enough for that.

Comment: I see. Well in any case, if in the future i was downloading something that dense is there a better way to do it than the one i outlined.

Answer (score 1):

> attempting levels 0-22 from the ESRI world imagery map

That would be about 23,456,248,059,220 tiles if you mean the whole world.

Even if it was just 500 bytes per tile on average, you would be looking at about **10 terabytes** for the tiles. And **trillions** of HTTP requests to the server(s).

Even if you just want to download smaller areas, it is an excessive usage of the service provided.

You don't want that and you should not do that. The terms of service probably forbid it and respect for the data providers does so too, if you think about ethically.

If you really require all this data, find your own big datasets and tile them yourself. Or find a provider that provides the imagery in appropriate data formats.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following article
https://help.inputapp.io/howto/settingup_background_map_rastertile

Using zoomlevels > 15 will result in very big files...
For field survey in an area of 10 km², I use the zoomlevel 12 - 15 or max 16/17.
Hope this helps.